# Gas Particle simulation Collision calculation C++

Tags: c++

This I feel is a rather complicated problem, I hope I can fit it in to small enough of a space to make it understandable. I'm presently writing code to

> simulate Ideal gas particles inside a box. I'm calculating if two particles will collide having calculated the time taken for them to reach their closest point. (using an example where they have head on collision).

In this section of code I need to find if they will collide at all for two particles, before then calculating at what time and how they collide etc.
Thus for my two paricles:

`Main.cpp`

```
Vector vp1(0,0,0);
Vector vv1(1,0,0);
Vector vp2(12,0,0);
Vector vv2(-1,0,0);
Particle Particle1(1, vp1, vv1);
Particle Particle2(1, vp2, vv2);
Particle1.timeToCollision(Particle2);
```

Within my program I define a particle to be:

Header File

```
class Particle {
private:

    Vector p;   //position
    Vector v;   //velocity
    double radius;   //radius

public:

    Particle();

    Particle(double r, const Vector Vecp, const Vector Vecv);

    void setPosition(Vector);
    void setVelocity(Vector);

    Vector getPosition() const;
    Vector getVelocity() const;

    double getRadius() const;

    void move(double t);

    double timeToCollision(const Particle particle);

    void collideParticles(Particle);

    ~Particle();
};
```

`Vector` is another class that in short gives `x`, `y`, `z` values. It also contains multiple functions for manipulating these.

---

**And the part that I need help with**, within the `.cpp` (Ignore the cout start and letters etc, they are simple checks where my code exits for tests.)

Given the equations:

[image]

I have already written code to do the dot product and modulus for me and:

[image: b^2=r(0)^2-s^2]

where

[image: s^2=((-r(0) dot product v)^2 / modulus squared v)]

`s` is distance travelled in time `tac`.

```
double Particle::timeToCollision(const Particle particle){
    Vector r2 = particle.getPosition();
    Vector r1 = p;
    Vector v2 = particle.getVelocity();
    Vector v1 = v;
    Vector r0 = r2 - r1;
    Vector v = v2 - v1;

    double modv;
    double tca;
    double result = 0;
    double bsqr;

    modv = getVelocity().modulus();

    cout << "start" << endl;

    if(modv < 0.0000001){
        cout << "a" << endl;
        result = FLT_MAX;
    }else{
        cout << "b" << endl;
        tca = ((--r0).dot(v)) / v.modulusSqr();

// -- is an overridden operator that gives the negation ( eg (2, 3, 4) to (-2, -3, -4) )
        if (tca < 0) {
            cout << "c" << endl;
            result = FLT_MAX;
        }else{
            cout << "d" << endl;
            Vector s(v.GetX(), v.GetY(), v.GetZ());
            s.Scale(tca);
            cout << getVelocity().GetX() << endl;
            cout << getVelocity().GetY() << endl;
            cout << getVelocity().GetZ() << endl;

            double radsqr = radius * radius;
            double bx = (r0.GetX() * r0.GetX() - (((r0).dot(v)) *((r0).dot(v)) / v.modulusSqr()));
            double by = (r0.GetY() * r0.GetY() - (((r0).dot(v)) *((r0).dot(v)) / v.modulusSqr()));
            double bz=(r0.GetZ() * r0.GetZ() - (((r0).dot(v)) * ((r0).dot(v)) / v.modulusSqr()));

            if (bsqr < 4 * radsqr) {
                cout << "e" << endl;
                result = FLT_MAX;
            } else {
            }
            cout << "tca: " << tca << endl;
        }
    }
    cout << "fin" << endl;
    return result;
}
```

I have equations for calculating several aspects, `tca` refers to Time of closest approach.

As written in the code I need to check if `b > 4 r^2`, I Have made some attempts and written the `X`, `Y` and `Z` components of `b` out. But I'm getting rubbish answers.
I just need help to establish if I've already made mistakes or the sort of direction I should be heading.

---

All my code prior to this works as expected and I've written multiple tests for each to check.

Please inform me in a comment for any information you feel I've left out etc.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: what is `getVelocity().modulus();` doing

Comment: I see. It is the L_2-norm of v

Comment: you never set a value for `double bsqr;`. It has random content. But you use a comparison `bsqr < 4*radsqr`. What is your exact output?

Comment: @Maikel   `double bsqr;` is the value of b^2, it needs to be a single double and the distance between the center of particles 1 and 2 at time tca, so that if it is greater then 4r^2 I know the particles dont collide. Both particles have radius one in this case.

Comment: You still never set it. You also do not set `result`. Define your output or what you mean with "you get rubbish".

Comment: @Maikel I believe I did that initially to stop the compiler complaining (concerning result). And by rubbish results I mean not what I expect. I get a value of 14 for b when I should get 0 at tca as they then occupy the same space (would have collided.)

Comment: If i understand it correctly they collide if `b^2 < 4r^2`, right?

Comment: Please don't post your whole code here. Instead, extract a minimal example that only demonstrates the issues you have.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt I would estimate this to be about 1/20th of my whole code. And what I have posted is where the problem lies in my opinion. Making it shorter would make it to vague to be of any use. I'll keep that in mind for future posts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My apologies for a very poorly worded question that was to long and bulky to make much sense of. Luckily I have found my own answer to be much easier then initially anticipated.

```
double Particle::timeToCollision(const Particle particle){

    Vector r2=particle.getPosition();
    Vector r1=p;
    Vector v2=particle.getVelocity();
    Vector v1=v;
    Vector r0=r2-r1;
    Vector v=v2-v1;

    double modv;
    double tca = ((--r0).dot(v)) / v.modulusSqr();
    double bsqr;

    double result=0;

    double rColTestx=r0.GetX()+v.GetX()*tca;
    double rColTesty=r0.GetY()+v.GetY()*tca;
    double rColTestz=r0.GetZ()+v.GetZ()*tca;

    Vector rtColTest(rColTestx, rColTesty, rColTestz);


    modv=getVelocity().modulus();

    cout << "start " << endl;

    if(modv<0.0000001){
        cout << "a" << endl;
        result=FLT_MAX;
    }else{
        cout << "b" << endl;

        if (tca < 0) {
            cout << "c" << endl;
            result=FLT_MAX;
        }else{
            cout << "d" << endl;
            Vector s(v.GetX(), v.GetY(), v.GetZ());
            s.Scale(tca);

            cout << getVelocity().GetX() << endl;
            cout << getVelocity().GetY() << endl;
            cout << getVelocity().GetZ() << endl;


           double radsqr= radius*radius;

            bsqr=rtColTest.modulusSqr();

            if (bsqr < 4*radsqr) {
                cout << "e" << endl;
                cout << "collision occurs" << endl;
                result = FLT_MAX;
            } else {
                cout << "collision does not occurs" << endl;
            }

        }

    }
    cout << "fin" << endl;
    return result;

}
```

Sorry its a large section of code. Also FLT_MAX is from the cfloat lib. I didn't stat this in my question. I found this to work for several examples I calculated on paper to check.

To be Clear, the `return result`and `result=0` were arbitrary. I later edit to return time but for this part didn't need or want that.

Answer (score 1):

You had several mistakes in your code. You never set `result` to a value different from `0` or `FLT_MAX`. You also never calculate `bsqr`. And I guess the collision happens if `bsqr < 4r^2` and not the other way round. (well i do not understand why `4r^2` instead of `r^2` but okay). Since you hide your vector implementation I used a common vector library. I also recommend to not use handcrafted stuff anyway. Take a look into armadillo or Eigen.

Here you go with a try in Eigen.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>
#include <type_traits>
#include "Eigen/Dense"

struct Particle {
    double radius;
    Eigen::Vector3d p;
    Eigen::Vector3d v;
};

template <class FloatingPoint>
    std::enable_if_t<std::is_floating_point<FloatingPoint>::value, bool>
        almost_equal(FloatingPoint x, FloatingPoint y, unsigned ulp=1)
        {
            FloatingPoint max = std::max(std::abs(x), std::abs(y));
            return std::abs(x-y) <= std::numeric_limits<FloatingPoint>::epsilon()*max*ulp;
        }

double timeToCollision(const Particle& left, const Particle& right){
    Eigen::Vector3d r0 = right.p - left.p;
    Eigen::Vector3d v  = right.v - left.v;

    double result = std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();

    double vv = v.dot(v);
    if (!almost_equal(vv, 0.)) {
        double tca = (-r0).dot(v) / vv;
        if (tca >= 0) {
            Eigen::Vector3d s = tca*v;
            double bb = r0.dot(r0) - s.dot(s);
            double radius = std::max(left.radius, right.radius);
            if (bb < 4*radius*radius)
                result = tca;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

int main()
{
    Eigen::Vector3d vp1 {0,0,0};
    Eigen::Vector3d vv1 {1,0,0};
    Eigen::Vector3d vp2 {12,0,0};
    Eigen::Vector3d vv2 {-1,0,0};
    Particle p1 {1, vp1, vv1};
    Particle p2 {1, vp2, vv2};
    std::cout << timeToCollision(p1, p2) << '\n';
}
```

Comment: This to me seems hugely complicated as I'd still consider myself at the introductory stage of programming. Thank you for the contribution though.

Comment: Just look at the function `timeToCollision`. It has half the length of yours and is straight forward. The rest of the source code is there just to complete the example and make it compilable.